# doxygen auto reference external links?

Tags: doxygen

I use some external libraries in my project, e.g. libev.

I realize I can use markdown (or href) and put
  [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html)
in my document.

However that only works in a single place, and I don't want to have to put that in the dozens of places I refer to libev.

If it's "ClientWatcher" (one of my classes), doxygen auto links to the class.

Is there some way to tell doxygen to make all occurrences of the word "libev" auto link to http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html (for example)

Answer (score 2):

If you add

```
ALIASES += libev="<a href=\"http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html\">libev</a>"
```

to Doxygen's configuration file you can use the `\libev` command to generate a link, like so

```
/** @mainpage
 *  See \libev for more info.
 */
```

Comment: I considered trying this. Not quite what I wanted, but certainly an improvement over specifying it in lots of places.